# How to replace HTML input value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string of html:

```
string = "<input type=text name='email' value='mike@mail.com'> <input type=hidden name='pin' value='123'>"
```

And I want replace the value of `email` to stars `*******`

```
"<input type=text name='email' value='*******'> <input type=hidden name='pin' value='123'>"
```

so I have something like this:

```
string.gsub(/<input(.*?)name='email'(.*)value='(.*?)'/, '*******')
```

https://regex101.com/r/dO1uJ3/2

I do know that my regex is invalid, so asking for help.

p.s I don't want to use Nokogiri, just plain regex with string

Comment: downvoter, what's wrong?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but you *really* want to use a proper HTML parser and not a regular expression. Code like this tends to be extremely brittle and breaks down when even the most minor of things changes. Changing the quoting style, forgetting quotes, switching the order of attributes, all of these things can and will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create capture groups (`()`) before and after of what you want to replace, then use them for replacement `\1****\2`, i.e.:

```
result = subject.gsub(/('email'\s+value=').*?('>)/i, '\1*****\2')
```

https://regex101.com/r/dO1uJ3/1

---

Comment: thanks, `\1****\2` what is purpose of `\1` and `\2`?

Comment: `\1` and `\2` represent the capture groups we've captured before with `( )`